# trying to register ios for push messaging

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush

I am currently trying to implement mobile push for a phonegap based ios release. I would like some clarification concerning some of the steps in the documentation provided. I am pretty new to ios development, and would like to avoid spending to much time on something some of you could find trivial.

Could you clarify what those steps in the documentation https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/journey-builder-for-apps/sdk-implementation/register-your-devices.html#cordova-ios mean?

2. Open that file and drop down the ETAppSettings.

and

3. Add #import "ETpush." to the top of the file with the rest of the imports. (Shouldn't I add each of them?)

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: Update. I managed to get past this and register my ios device with exactTarget, which is a step forward. I however do not receive the notifications once I send them from the mobile-connect interface. I am trying to understand this now :).

Comment: Hey Alexh, might be worth removing this question now, but you could actually post an answer explaining how you did it (which is allowed on SFSE!). Maybe if you can't work out the new thing post a new question for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

For step two, "Open that file and drop down the ETAppSettings", no additional work was necessary. It all worked straight away.

For step three, I had to add:

#import "ETPush.h" 
#import "ETSdkWrapper.h" 
 for the device to register.